# message box not displayed after event completes c#

Tags: c#

We have C# web application ,on button click event we do a data load process using stored procedure which runs for 3 hours,after the procedure finish loading we display a message box using code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), scriptString, true);
radiobuttion.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

Ιf the procedure completes in 1 hour things are fine, if it runs for more than 2 hours, the page turns unresponsive (message box not displayed, radio button not changed). Ι tried debug, the code process through all lines and completes with no display. Can anyone help?

Comment: What if you put the procedure as a asynchronous request? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx Of course, you could just plug the async if you already used the latest .NET

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an ASP .NET application, either your stored procedure is timing out or Session is abandoned by the time the procedure returns, thus no controls will work. Check your Session State right before the messagebox/radio button actions take place.

Comment: i have checked it session sate is active